# Vb.net Passing Dataset between functions

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issues when passing Dataset from a Class Function to another Function. If I have all of the code in a form everything works fine. The sequence is that Students is called in a button then Updates is called in another button. When I click the update button I get an error of the object is not set. I see that OdataAdapter isn't being populated. All Updates is doing to updating a datagridview that was populated by Students.

MY Function in ClientSide CLASS called Students

```
Public Sub Students()
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Students"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    ODataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd2)
  Dim builder As OracleCommandBuilder = New OracleCommandBuilder(ODataAdapter)
    myDataSet = New DataSet()
    dt = New DataTable
    ODataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    Form1.DataGridView3.DataSource = dt
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

MY Function in ClientSide CLASS called Updates

```
Public Sub Updates()

    Using conn = New OracleConnection(ODataAdapter)
        conn.Open()
        ODataAdapter.Update(dt)
        myDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

My Form that calls updates

```
Private Sub Update_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Update.Click, Update.Click
    Dim myClassInstance As New ClientSide         
myClassInstance.Updates() 
End Sub
```

Comment: If the dataadapter is global to the class, you dont have to pass it *and* you dont have to rebuild the command objects for each operation.

Comment: I did have the Table Adapter as Global. At the class and Form level. It still gives me an error when running update stating that it doesn't have anything filled in

Comment: but your commandbuilder is local.  when the thing that creates the update, insert etc commands goes away so will the command objects it built.

Comment: If that is the case what is cause the datagrid to not update.... I was assuming it was because of the datatableadapater. LIke I said it works if I have it all in one form.

Comment: Actually it appears to be failing at myDataSet.AcceptChanges(). It looks like my dataset is blank